# KQL simplification of multiple string.contains queries

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-search, kql

For SharePoint search, I create a KQL query that, among other things, sometimes checks whether an entity has one of several interesting substrings appearing in one particular property.

The property itself is a comma-separated list of integral IDs, and every atom of my body dislikes this solution, but apparently it works and at this point in time, it's what I'm working with.

So, we have the property `ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName` that can look something like `245, 2451, 21, 96612, 5215`.

And so a query can contain this:

`(ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:29 OR ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:30 OR ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:31 OR ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:32 OR ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:33 OR ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:34 OR ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:20 OR ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:35 OR ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:36 OR ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:21 OR ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:427382 )`

So the question is, can I simplify this to something like

`ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:(29 OR 30 OR 21 OR 32 OR 33 OR 34 OR 20 OR 35 OR 36 OR 21 OR 427382)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the query text as :

```
ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:29 OR 30 OR 21 OR 32 OR 33 OR 34 OR 20 OR 35 OR 36 OR 21 OR 427382
```

I use the query text get the relevant results:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that does indeed work syntactially! However, I get more results this way. Any idea of why? My original query gets 120,537 rows (total, and including duplicates), this other form gets 1,047,946 total and 1,257,535 with duplicates.

Comment: An entry with this value `6,41,85976,96052,244787,244791,244792,244793` gets returned by `ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:30 OR 427382` but not by `(ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:30 OR ReallyLongAndCumbersomeName:427382)`. I don't understand why.

Comment: I have `OtherProperty` with the value `0427382` on this very entity, so I guess that should be why it gets returned. And so I don't think this works like I was hoping?